# Calling methods in jar from a rails application

Tags: jar, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a web application in ruby-on-rails 4. There are some jar files of another application with which i have to integrate my application. I have to call some methods of the class files contained in jars.
Please let me know how can i call methods in jar files from my RoR application?
Any pointers/links will help.
Thanks.

Comment: What is your question? It is not clear what you are asking... please provide as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out [jruby](http://jruby.org/). It's an implementation of ruby that runs in a JVM and has access to everything that a java app would. [Here](https://blogs.oracle.com/coolstuff/entry/using_java_classes_in_jruby) are instructions on using jars and java classes with jruby. You can still use rails with jruby.

Heroku has a [migration guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/moving-an-existing-rails-app-to-run-on-jruby) that details moving from ruby on rails to jruby on rails that might help you out, as not all gems are compatible with jruby.